# draw transparent 3d cube model in arcore android

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

i have create cube using shapefactor in arcore android but it is not transparent. How can can i make model transparent so in which it is placed It shows the background view. I have found only below method for create 3d cube model

```
MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithColor(this,new Color(248,248,248))
                .thenAccept(
                        material -> {
                          ShapeFactory.makeCube(vector3, Vector3.zero(), material);

                        });
```

PLease help for making cube semi transparent so i can background view will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the alpha value of your color:

`public Color (float r, float g, float b, float a)`

```
new Color(248,248,248, /* alpha value here */)
```